# How does Django rename uploaded files?

Tags: django, django-uploads

If upload a file `image.png` from a web browser, a new file named `image.png` will appear in the upload directory on the server.

If I then upload another file named `image.png` (same name), a new file named `image_aj642zm.png` will appear in the upload directory on the server.

Then, if I upload another file named `image.png` (again the same name), a new file named `image_z6z2BaQ.png` will appear in the upload directory on the server.

What method does Django use to rename the uploaded file if a file with that name already exists in the upload directory?
(i.e. where does the extra `_aj642zm` and `_z6z2BaQ` come from?)

The usual set-up:

In models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')
```

In forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Image

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ['image']
```

In views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ImageForm

def upload_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = ImageForm()

    return render(request, 'upload_file.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Check upload_to parameter in your model definition.

Comment: @BipulJain The upload_to argument specifies where to put the uploaded file. It doesn't say anything about the renaming scheme. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You can specify a method there. Which should have renaming the logic.

Comment: Please share whatever relevant code you have. As far as I know Django doesn't do anything like this on its own.

Comment: @Chris it actually does this by default inside Storage class  if name is same :)

Comment: @iklinac, [right you are](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.save)!

Comment: @iklinac it does it in my local storage but apparently it's disabled in my production server... do you know how to enable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django default Storage class method called [get_available_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage.get_available_name)

```
    # If the filename already exists, add an underscore and a random 7
    # character alphanumeric string (before the file extension, if one
    # exists) to the filename until the generated filename doesn't exist.
    # Truncate original name if required, so the new filename does not
    # exceed the max_length.
```

Django by default saves object by its name but if object with that name already exists adds up underscore and 7 random chars as quoted in code comment

Also as addition to this Django Storage class method get_valid_name parses up file name before and replaces all spaces with underscores and removes all chars that are not unicode, alpha, dash, underscore or dot

```
re.sub(r'(?u)[^-\w.]', '', s)
```

Comment: how can I enable this in my production server? for some reason it's not doing it there.